# Python script does not work when invoked in external USB

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, fasta

I am trying to convert ab1 files to fasta files using a python script.

```
import os
import sys
from Bio import SeqIO

# get the names of all AB1 files in the current directory
ab1_files = [f for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith('.ab1')]

# loop through each AB1 file and convert it to FASTA format
for ab1_file in ab1_files:
    fasta_file = os.path.splitext(ab1_file)[0] + '.fasta'  # create the output file name
    with open(ab1_file, 'rb') as ab1_handle, open(fasta_file, 'w') as fasta_handle:
        SeqIO.convert(ab1_handle, 'abi', fasta_handle, 'fasta')

# concatenate all the resulting FASTA files into a single file
all_fasta_file = 'all_sequences.fasta'
with open(all_fasta_file, 'w') as all_fasta_handle:
    for ab1_file in ab1_files:
        fasta_file = os.path.splitext(ab1_file)[0] + '.fasta'
        header = '>' + ab1_file + '\n'
        with open(fasta_file, 'r') as fasta_handle:
            sequence = fasta_handle.read().strip()
            all_fasta_handle.write(header + sequence + '\n')
        os.remove(fasta_file)  # delete the individual FASTA file

print('All AB1 files converted to FASTA format and concatenated into ' + all_fasta_file)
```

The scenario is that I have already installed the required modules and necessary dependencies. I have made it worked as well on my Mac zsh terminal. I have used this twice and the first time worked perfectly. The second time is also perfect and the script run smoothly. Nevertheless, I figured out that I run into an error whenever I run the script in my external USB. I invoked the script while it is saved in my external drive and would get an error like below. At first I thought that it was because of file format or my conda, but upon checking and confirming, there is no problem with the files I am trying to convert.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "01_ab1_to_fasta.py", line 12, in <module>
    SeqIO.convert(ab1_handle, 'abi', fasta_handle, 'fasta')
  File "/Users/pmi12/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py", line 1072, in convert
    records = parse(in_file, in_format)
  File "/Users/pmi12/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py", line 605, in parse
    return iterator_generator(handle)
  File "/Users/pmi12/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/AbiIO.py", line 353, in __init__
    super().__init__(source, mode="b", fmt="ABI")
  File "/Users/pmi12/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/Interfaces.py", line 63, in __init__
    self.records = self.parse(self.stream)
  File "/Users/pmi12/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/AbiIO.py", line 364, in parse
    raise OSError(f"File should start ABIF, not {marker!r}")
OSError: File should start ABIF, not b'\x00\x05\x16\x07'
```

I hope someone can explain why this is happening. Why am I getting an error whenever the script is in my external flash drive and not when it is on my local drive.

EDIT: I am using Mac Mini with M1 (2020). Might be relevant?

Comment: To start debugging, have your script print the name of the offending file when it gets that error. Inspect the file manually. See if it's all what you expect.

Comment: @Jeff, Thank you for the suggestion. it seems like the script is accessing other files that it is not meant to access so it goes onto error. I think I did something wrong even though the script specifies that it should only access ab1 files.